# ListView Populates multiple times on button click

Tags: android, json, listview, arraylist, android-volley

I have an app that displays data from my server

Now my issue is that I have a Listview that is populated with JSON data from the server
this  is to display Time Logged, I have a To-Date and a from-date  edit text to enter the needede dates

And everytime I click the button the list view populates but the previous loaded data stays in the listview

What I want to achieve is that everytime the button is clicked the previous data is cleared and only the new data is displayed

I am using volley to GET the Json from the server

I have tried setting a custom Adapter, setting adapter to Null

Here is my On click

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri.Builder builder2=new Uri.Builder();
            builder2.scheme("https")
                    .authority("www.FAKEWEBSiTE.co.za")
                    .appendPath("DATA.asp")
                    .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                    .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                    .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                    .appendQueryParameter("FromDate", FromDate.getText().toString().trim())
                    .appendQueryParameter("ToDate", ToDate.getText().toString().trim());
            URL2=builder2.build().toString();
            LoadReport(URL2);
```

Here is the code where I load the JSON etc.

```
private void LoadReport(String url) {
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(reportActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Time Log Data");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                pd.cancel();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String key=jsonObject1.keys().next();
                            String task=jsonObject1.getString(key);
                            Project.add(task);


                        }
                        report.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(reportActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Project));
                        report.setClickable(false);



                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.cancel();

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout=30000;
        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your list that you are passing to your adapter each time you click on button

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if(Project!=null){
       Project.clear();
       }
        Uri.Builder builder2=new Uri.Builder();
        builder2.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.FAKEWEBSiTE.co.za")
                .appendPath("DATA.asp")
                .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                .appendQueryParameter("FromDate", FromDate.getText().toString().trim())
                .appendQueryParameter("ToDate", ToDate.getText().toString().trim());
        URL2=builder2.build().toString();
        LoadReport(URL2);
```